# Background color mismatch in vim and tmux

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, colors, iterm

I'm having trouble getting the full range of colors to work in vim when I'm running through tmux. I belive that it's some sort of trouble with TERM variables or 256colors, but I've done everything I have been able to find online to get 256 colors working in vim, tmux, and iTerm, and nothing has fixed it. It's a small problem, but it seriously bugs me.

Here's an example code file in vim just through iTerm:
[image: iTerm]

and here's the same file in vim through tmux and iTerm:
[image]

Notice how the background colors seem slightly mismatched, only when code is written there. Why could this be?

I have `set t_Co=256` in my `vimrc`, my iTerm terminal is set to `xterm-256color`, I have `set -g default-terminal xterm-256color` in my `tmux.conf`, and I have:

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
     export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
     export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

in my `.profile`. This exact issue is replicated on my Ubuntu based machine at work, and I use all of the same configuration files there. This at least isolates the issue as not being OS/iTerm related.

Comment: I think you need to set `TERM=screen-256color` inside tmux.

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't work. Out of curiosity, why would that be better than xterm-256color?

Actually, I take that back. I tried setting it in my tmux.conf which didn't fix anything, but if I run export TERM=screen-256color from inside tmux it fixes it. Why does that make sense?

Comment: I had a similar problem but `export TERM=screen-256color` just disables all coloring.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095377/96855

Answer (score 17):

An old question but it ranked high on my Google search without helping me. This is what finally solved this for me

In **.tmux.conf**:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
```

In **.vimrc**:

```
if exists('+termguicolors')
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  set termguicolors
endif
```

Comment: +1 I searched the whole web, spent hours and hours trying to fix this and it wasn't working until I find this answer. My problem was that after setting the TERM variable on xterm-256color, I had the colors in vim but they weren't the right colors. It was like there is a pink overlay on top of the terminal and everything was getting this pinkish color! For me, the second line of your **.tmux.conf** file was a game-changer. I simply added `set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"` and it magically worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SaeedAhadian same! Thanks, @Martin!

Comment: Neovim 0.9.1, Tmux 3.3a, Terminator on Kubuntu -- This worked for me

Answer (score 8):

After adding the line below into `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

You still need to add the line below into `.vimrc`

```
set term=screen-256color
```

Finally, the alias need to be added to `.bashrc`

```
alias tmux='tmux -2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside tmux, you need to set `TERM=screen-256color`. It may be something like [here](https://superuser.com/a/399326/117820) that this only works from inside tmux, but not in `tmux.conf`. Check that you don't unconditionally overwrite the `TERM` value, e.g. in your `.bashrc`, or anything that gets sourced when you open a shell inside tmux.